# How to add duration to localscroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, href

I'm using a very simple system to get my page to auto scroll

```
<a class="nav" href="#about">
 About
</a>

<div class="page-section clear" id="about">
</div>

$.localScroll();
```

Now I'm trying to achieve some duration and or easing. Is it possible to do this without adding any more jquery?

I've tried `$.localScroll({duration: 3000});` for example, to no avail

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for that. You can use jQuery for that.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rSazd/)

```
$("a.nav").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var h = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;

    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: h}, 1000); // here is the duration, in ms
});
```

For more information, and the possibility for easing (available!), check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).